# Demonstration of the Borel-Cantelli lemma

Tags: limits, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I am trying to understand the demonstration of the Borel-Cantelli lemma:

> Let $(A_n)$ be a sequence of independent events. If $ \sum_n P(A_n) = \infty $, then $P( \lim \sup A_n ) = 1$

To show that $ P( ( \lim \sup A_n ) ) = 1 $, we have to prove that $ P( ( \lim \sup A_n )^c ) = 0 $:

$ P( ( \lim \sup A_n )^c ) =  P( \cup_p \cap_{n \geq p} A_n^c ) \leq \sum_p P( \cap_{n \geq p} A_n^c ) $.

Then the demonstration focuses on showing that $P( \cap_{n \geq p} A_n^c ) = 0 ~ \forall p$, using $ 1-x \leq \exp(-x) $. Then it says that $ \sum_p P( \cap_{n \geq p} A_n^c ) = 0 $, and therefore  $ P( ( \lim \sup A_n )^c ) = 0 $ which is what we wanted.

The part that is unclear to me is how we go from $$P( \cap_{n \geq p} A_n^c ) = 0 ~ \forall p$$ to $$ \sum_p P( \cap_{n \geq p} A_n^c ) = 0 $$ Why do we jump from the finite case to infinity? What happened?

**===== EDIT =====**

I read the proof of the lemma on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma), and I don't understand it either. I guess the part that I fail to understand is the same in both versions:

To show that $\lim_N P( \cap_{n \geq N} E_n^c) = 0 $, Wikipedia says:

> it is enough to show: $ P( \cap_{n \geq N} E_n^c) = 0 $

There again, I don't understand. Why is something true for all $N$, also true at infinity?

Comment: If $x_p=0$ for every $p$ in a countable set then $\sum\limits_px_p=$ $____$?

Comment: @Did Now I am confused. Does $x_p=0 ~ \forall p $ imply that  $\lim_p x_p = 0 $?

Comment: Why, yes! But this is not the question, is it?

Comment: @Did I thought it was, since $ \sum_p x_p = \lim_n \sum_{p=1}^n x_p $

Comment: Would you be confusing the limit of $x_p$ and the limit of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^px_i$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a sequence $x_1, x_2, x_3, ...$ where each term is zero.

Then

1. $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (0) = 0$$
2. $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_i = \lim_{n \to \infty} (0) = 0$$

Another way to look at #2:

Consider the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ where

$$f(x) = 0$$

We have

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} (0) = 0$$

---

In our case:

1.

> how we go from $$P( \cap_{n \geq p} A_n^c ) = 0 ~ \forall p$$ to $$ \sum_p P( \cap_{n \geq p} A_n^c ) = 0 $$

$$\sum_p P( \cap_{n \geq p} A_n^c ) = \sum_p (0) = 0$$

2.

$$\lim_N P( \cap_{n \geq N} E_n^c) = \lim_N 0 = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{n}0 =\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0 $